# postgreSql-16 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, postgresql

This has occurred intermittently since using postgreSql.
postgreSql version is 16.
The DB Server is duplicated.

I don't know why this error occurs.
Please Help me.

```
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at com.vc.mdl.adm.session.SSOLoginFilter.doFilter(SSOLoginFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) at com.vc.fw.core.mvc.cntr.ValueChainServiceInvoker.invoke(ValueChainServiceInvoker.java:28) ... 46 more Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.getTransaction(ChainedTransactionManager.java:145) at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.getTransaction(ChainedTransactionManager.java:69) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy39.execute(Unknown Source) ... 50 more Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:309) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) at org.springframework.data.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.registerTransactionManager(MultiTransactionStatus.java:69) at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.getTransaction(ChainedTransactionManager.java:124) ... 57 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354) at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263) at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443) at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297) at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy.connect(DriverSpy.java:401) at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681) at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190) at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155) at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146) at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:265) ... 61 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:288) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:314) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:355) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:808) at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966) at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161) at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128) at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113) at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73) at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:465) at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:589) at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:191) at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258) ... 73 more
```

I used the options below, but it didn't help.

hostRecheckSeconds,

sslmode=disable

And Shutdown Standby Server.